# LoadError (Unable to autoload constant Api::V1::UserTokenController) Knock Gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authentication, ruby-on-rails-6

As this is a brand new App, I'm using Rails 6 beta.

I'm trying to use the Knock Gem, but when trying to get an API response from posting a user I get this error:

> LoadError (Unable to autoload constant Api::V1::UserTokenController,
>   expected
>   /Users/Simon/Sites/TGD/ginbackend/app/controllers/api/v1/user_token_controller.rb
>   to define it):

However, I do have `user_token_controller.rb` file in that location.  I'm using a namespace for my API endpoint:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do

  namespace :api do
    namespace :v1 do
      post 'user_token' => 'user_token#create' # <= manually placed this under the namespace
      resources :distilleries
      resources :botanicals
      resources :gins
      resources :botanicals_gins
    end
   end
end
```

As per the Knock documentation, I have also updated my `application_controller.rb`, do note this is located at `app/controllers/` and not `app/controllers/api/v1` **is that an issue?**

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::API
    include Knock::Authenticable

    private

    def authenticate_v1_user
      authenticate_for V1::User
    end

end
```

Answer (score 2):

Solved.

It's all in the details (as always).

As the knock installer auto generated `user_token_controller` it didn't know about my routes namespace.

So I Changed:

```
class UserTokenController < Knock::AuthTokenController
```

to:

```
class Api::V1::UserTokenController < Knock::AuthTokenController
```